# How to Redirect with UI Router When Session Expires in Firebase

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I'm using Angular with Firebase and UI Router. I'm using anonymous authentication. When a session expires, I would like the unauthenticated user to be redirected to the homepage. I've used the Yeoman Angularfire Generator as a model. But when I use the code below, an authenticated page does not redirect when a user is already on that page and the session expires.

```
.config(['$urlRouterProvider', 'SECURED_ROUTES', function($urlRouterProvider, SECURED_ROUTES) {
    $urlRouterProvider.whenAuthenticated = function(path, route) {
        route.resolve = route.resolve || {};
        route.resolve.user = ['Auth', function(Auth) {
            return Auth.$requireAuth();
        }];
        $urlRouterProvider.when(path, route);
        SECURED_ROUTES[path] = true;
        return $urlRouterProvider;
    };
}])
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Auth', 'SECURED_ROUTES', '$state',
    function($rootScope, $location, Auth, SECURED_ROUTES, $state) {

        Auth.$onAuth(check);

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {

            if (error === 'AUTH_REQUIRED') {
                $state.go('home');
            }
            else {
                console.log('authenticated');
            }
        });

        function check(user) {

            if (!user && authRequired($location.path())) {

                $state.go('home');
            }
        }

        function authRequired(path) {
            return SECURED_ROUTES.hasOwnProperty(path);
        }
    }
])
.constant('SECURED_ROUTES', {});
```

Router

```
.state('selection', {
    url: '/selection',
    authRequired: true,
    views: {

        'list': {

            templateUrl: 'app/views/project-list.html',
            controller: 'ProjectListCtrl as projectList',
            resolve: {    
              'user': ['Auth', function(Auth) {
                  return Auth.$waitForAuth();
               }]
             }
        },
        'selectionlist': {

            templateUrl: 'app/views/selection-list.html',
            controller: 'SelectionListCtrl as selectionList'
            resolve: {    
              'user': ['Auth', function(Auth) {
                  return Auth.$waitForAuth();
               }]
             }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you tried smth like $state.transitionTo('home', $stateParams, { reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true }); ?

Comment: Are you trying to make the client detect the expired session (like my online banking account timing out after 15-30 mins?). Or does the client make a server request, and you just need to handle the expired session?

Comment: @Sunil D. I want the client to detect an expired session (like online banking accounts).

Comment: @SunilD. Any thoughts on how to get this working?

Comment: @Ken You need to use some form of a timer, it looks like the answers below have been edited/added to reflect a couple of approaches. I like the idea proposed by @jbdev below... using the `expires` value from that `Auth` service is great .. no guessing about when it expires, so you don't have to run a timer that fired every minute (or whatever) to check if the session has expired.

Answer (score 8):

This is a common problem in Single Page Applications. With Angular you can solve it with *$http* interceptor.

The idea is if the session is expired the first time when the user needs some action from the backend to be redirected to the login page.
Expired session is detected from the response itself.

Example:

```
.factory('httpAuthInterceptor', function ($q) {
  return {
    'responseError': function (response) {
      // NOTE: detect error because of unauthenticated user
      if ([401, 403].indexOf(response.status) >= 0) {
        // redirecting to login page
        $state.go('home');
        return response;
      } else {
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
    }
  };
})

.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpAuthInterceptor');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but, unfortunately, this code doesn't seem to be working for me when using Firebase.

Comment: @Ken what's your problem with this code? I basically use an interceptor like this in all my angular applications

Comment: Shouldn't the code be `return $q.reject(response);`? - rejection is not an argument for responseError.

Comment: @neridaj, 'rejection' stands for a pseudo variable, it could be anything that makes sense in your scenario. Cheers!

Comment: as per i know - `$state` you can't use inside .factory method

Answer (score 3):

Have you read through this?

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html

I'd read the "Authenticating with Routers" section.

**Edit**

In that case you can grab the 'expires' value from Auth.$getAuth() and use it in a $timeout on $routeChangeSuccess.  Essentially creating a countdown to session timeout after every route change...like so:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function() {
    var sessionTimeout = Auth.$getAuth().expires * 1000;
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();

    var timer = sessionTimeout - n;

    console.log(timer);

    $timeout(function() {
        $location.path("/");
    },timer);
});
```

Comment: jbdev Yes, I've read through it many times. As I noted in my question, I'm not having any trouble redirecting if transitioning to an unauthenticated page. The problem is getting the page to automatically redirect if the user is already on an unauthenticated page when a session expires.

Answer (score 1):

As you said "when a user is already on that page and the session expires.", that case you can use

```
$location.path('/home')
```

And for auto detect idle session expiration [Ng-Idle](http://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng-idle/), see the demo

Comment: Since he uses ui router I would suggest `$state.go('home'); instead of using `$location` for this.

Comment: $state.go('home') will not do anything if you are on the same page, that's what he already mentioned

Comment: `$state.go($state.current, $stateParams, {reload: true, inherit: false});` will reload the site no matter what

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the redirect working with UI Router by modifying the following code from my question above:

From this (not working):

```
function check(user) {

        if (!user && authRequired($location.path())) {

            $state.go('home');
        }
    }
```

To this (working):

```
function check(user) {

          if(!user && $state.current.authRequired===true) {

            $state.go('home');
          }
          else {console.log('logged in')}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of ajaxSetup in order to catch 301 errors, something like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (jqXHR.status == 0) {
            alert("Element not found.");
        } else {
            alert("Error: " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
        }
    }
});
```